# Help me identify this Japanese font (font found)

Tags: font-identification, japanese

Can anyone help me find this font's name please? It's from a song called mental chainsaw, tried font identification sites and it was not helpful unfortunately [image][image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Have you tried https://en.likefont.com/ ? - The site can recognise many Japanese fonts automatically. Sorry I can't do it for you as I can't read or write in Japanese. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you tried en.likefont.com ? - The site can recognise many Japanese fonts automatically. Sorry I can't do it for you as I can't read or write in Japanese. Good luck. - @billykerr

I have found the font. Thank you so much Billy Kerr the font is called **TA-F1blockline Regular** and can be found on [Adobe Fonts](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/ta-f1blockline).

[image: TA-F1 blockline regular]

Comment: Hey Lu-chan. Glad you found your answer! I took the liberty of adding the comment and an example link and image into your answer. If you want to change or add anything, you can hit the [edit] button under your answer to do so.